# Bubble sort letters

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

I could use some help with this code, it is almost done. I just need to convert it back to letters, but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how it should be done?

```
namespace Sorteringen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                int[] letters = { 'c', 's', 'a', 'k', 'x', 'l', 'j' };
                int t;

                for (int j = 0; j <= letters.Length - 2; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= letters.Length - 2; i++)
                    {
                        if (letters[i] > letters[i + 1])
                        {
                            t = letters[i + 1];
                            letters[i + 1] = letters[i];
                            letters[i] = t;
                        }
                    }                   
                }               
               foreach (int aray in letters)
               Console.WriteLine(aray +  " " );
               Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to declare `aray` as a `char` instead of an `int`. I'd recommend a clearer variable name as well:

```
foreach (char ch in letters)
    Console.Write(ch +  " " );
```

Also, why not just declare `letters` as a `char[]` and `t` as a `char`?

```
char[] letters = { 'c', 's', 'a', 'k', 'x', 'l', 'j' };
char t;

for (int j = 0; j <= letters.Length - 2; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= letters.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        if (letters[i] > letters[i + 1])
        {
            t = letters[i + 1];
            letters[i + 1] = letters[i];
            letters[i] = t;
        }
    }                   
}
```

Then you can just use `string.Join` to output the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", letters));
```